# Why is there no UTF-24?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, utf-32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why UTF-32 exists whereas only 21 bits are necessary to encode every character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339756/why-utf-32-exists-whereas-only-21-bits-are-necessary-to-encode-every-character)

The maximum Unicode code point is 0x10FFFF in UTF-32. UTF-32 has 21 information bits and 11 superfluous blank bits. So why is there no UTF-24 encoding (i.e. UTF-32 with the high byte removed) for storing each code point in 3 bytes rather than 4?

Comment: The simple reason is because there isn't a 24 structure. There is 16, 32, 8, 2 so 24 would be odd. Plus blocks of memory are normally dished out in blocks of 2^x....Its the same reason computere didn't come with 24MB or HDD's are not advertised with 24GB instead of 16GB and 32GB.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Well, the truth is : UTF-24 was suggested in 2007 :

http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2007-m01/0057.html

The mentioned pros & cons being :

> ```
> "UTF-24 
> Advantages: 
>  1. Fixed length code units. 
>  2. Encoding format is easily detectable for any content, even if mislabeled. 
>  3. Byte order can be reliably detected without the use of BOM, even for single-code-unit data. 
>  4. If octets are dropped / inserted, decoder can resync at next valid code unit. 
>  5. Practical for both internal processing and storage / interchange. 
>  6. Conversion to code point scalar values is more trivial then for UTF-16 surrogate pairs 
>     and UTF-7/8 multibyte sequences. 
>  7. 7-bit transparent version can be easily derived. 
>  8. Most compact for texts in archaic scripts. 
> Disadvantages: 
>  1. Takes more space then UTF-8/16, except for texts in archaic scripts. 
>  2. Comparing to UTF-32, extra bitwise operations required to convert to code point scalar values. 
>  3. Incompatible with many legacy text-processing tools and protocols. "
> ```

As pointed out by David Starner in http://www.mail-archive.com/unicode@unicode.org/msg16011.html :

> Why? UTF-24 will almost invariably be larger then UTF-16, unless you
>   are talking a document in Old Italic or Gothic. The math alphanumberic
>   characters will almost always be combined with enough ASCII to make
>   UTF-8 a win, and if not, enough BMP characters to make UTF-16 a win.
>   Modern computers don't deal with 24 bit chunks well; in memory, they'd
>   take up 32 bits a piece, unless you declared them packed, and then
>   they'd be a lot slower then UTF-16 or UTF-32. And if you're storing to
>   disk, you may as well use BOCU or SCSU (you're already going
>   non-standard), or use standard compression with UTF-8, UTF-16, BOCU or
>   SCSU. SCSU or BOCU compressed should take up half the space of UTF-24,
>   if that.

You could also check the following StackOverflow post :

[Why UTF-32 exists whereas only 21 bits are necessary to encode every character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339756/why-utf-32-exists-whereas-only-21-bits-are-necessary-to-encode-every-character)

Comment: The second quote was actually some years earlier, from 2003, in reply to my proposal.

Comment: Personally, I'd like to see them expand.  I know there is still a ton of space left, but they haven't done every language yet either, esp historic languages.

Comment: I believe that in Python, UTF24-like strings are the default.